# Unity ECS: Insert array of components into IJobProcessComponentData

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-game-engine

[Fix at the buttom]
I'm making a small simulation with birds, where a bird must do different things depending on where other birds are.
So I would like to insert an array of positions (where the other birds are) into an IJobProcessComponentData as seen in the code below. However, when the code runs I get an Error:

> InvalidOperationException: The NativeContainer
>   CohesionJob.Data.Neighbours.Birds has been deallocated. All containers
>   must be valid when scheduling a job.

```
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Transforms;
using Unity.Transforms2D;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Burst;

public class CohesionSystem : JobComponentSystem
{
    public struct BirdsData
    {
        [ReadOnly]
        public ComponentDataArray<Bird> Birds;
        [ReadOnly]
        public ComponentDataArray<Position> Pos;
        public int Length;
    }

 [Inject] BirdsData OtherBirds;

 public struct CohesionJob : IJobProcessComponentData<Bird, Position, Cohesion>
 {
    public BirdsData Neighbours;

    public void Execute([ReadOnly] ref Bird bird, ref Position position, ref Cohesion cohesion)
    {
        float3 center = new float3();
        int amount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Neighbours.Length; i++)
        {
            if(Vector3.Distance(Neighbours.Pos[i].Value, position.Value) <= cohesion.Radius)
            {
                center += Neighbours.Pos[i].Value;
                amount++;
            }
        }

        center /= amount;

        center = position.Value - center;

        cohesion.Value = center;
    }
 }

 protected override JobHandle OnUpdate(JobHandle inputDeps)
 {
    var job = new CohesionJob
    {
        Neighbours = OtherBirds
    };
    return job.Schedule(this, 64, inputDeps);
 }
}
```

So to fix this I had to copy the "OtherBirds.Pos" array and the code to do so is shown below:

```
protected override JobHandle OnUpdate(JobHandle inputDeps)
    {
        var job = new CohesionJob
        {
            Neighbours = new NativeArray<Position>(OtherBirds.Pos.GetChunkArray(0, OtherBirds.Pos.Length), Allocator.Temp)
        };
        return job.Schedule(this, 64, inputDeps);
    }
```

Comment: I am about to jump into the ECS system myself, however I believe you may have to make a "copy" of the data and pass it to your job var that way...  as the positions that would be stored in your "otherBirds" would only transfered as a reference over, which is something you would want to avoid (Hence all your birds would be updating their own positions, which would be modifying a value that another bird would be looking at.)

Comment: @Eddge, Yea that worked. Thanks, I have changed the description to include the fix.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for posting how you did that I will check this later if I run into the same issue.

Comment: If you run into `A Native Collection has not been disposed, resulting in a memory leak.`, mark the NativeArray member of your job with `[DeallocateNativeContainerOnJobCompletion]`

Comment: @sharvey I did not know that existed, but that is very handy. Tanks.